# Java 8 Stream return property or null

Tags: java

Is there a way using streams to return the property of a bean or null if the bean isn't present?

Something like:

```
String property = beans.stream()
    .filter(bean -> bean.getId() == id).findFirst().orElse(null).beanProperty();
```

Comment: Yes, you can use `Optional` method `map` (just move the `orElse` to the end).

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do with the code you added. That code won't compile, so it's not  clear what you are attempting.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, was banging my head trying to get the order of the methods correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, Let's write some lines of code that we will then analyse.

The best way to achieve this is to do the following:

```
String property = beans.stream()
    .filter(bean -> bean.getId() == id)
    .findFirst()
    .map(Property::beanProperty)
    .orElse(null);
```

A bit of explanations is in order here:

- First, we filter the list of properties using a `Stream` in order to keep only the properties with the given id with the method `filter`. This transforms a `Stream` to a `Stream`;
- Then, we get the bean property with a `map`. Please note that this method will apply the desired mapping function to the content of the `Optional` if and only if the latter is not empty. Also note that I assumed we had a POJO called `Property` for our properties and that I used a method reference to get the property. It would be equivalent to write `.map(prop -> prop.beanProperty())`;
- Finally, we call `orElse` of `Optional` that is equivalent in either taking the content of the Optional if not empty or taking the value given in parameter, in our case `null`.

As a final word, please take care that the signature of the `map` function is the following:

```
public<U> Optional<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper)
```

The latter is therefore applying the function on a `Optional` and returning an `Optional`.